# Can't figure out the wrong in this piece of code, alwaays gettin empty array as the second respond

Tags: reactjs

```js
const [enteredUser,setUser] = useState([]);
    
const addUserHandler =  (uNmae,uAge) => {
  
  setUser((prevUserList) => {
    console.log(uNmae)
    return [...prevUserList,{name : uNmae,age:uAge}];
  });
  console.log("entered user ", enteredUser);
};
```

The first log gives correct output but the second log always return empty, I am new to react.

I am expecting entered user as `[userName, userAge]` but always getting `[]`.

Comment: Because `setState` isn't updating the state synchronously for performance reasons...

Answer (score 0):

With react functional components you won't see the updated state right after the `setState` hook being called .

Perhaps you need a `useEffect` with a dependency to log the updated state :

```
useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("entered user ", enteredUser);
} , [enteredUser])
```

With **class components** we can have a callback function after `setState` updates the current state like this :

```
this.setState({
   enteredUser : "new user"
} , () => console.log(this.state.enteredUser) )
```

Comment: return (
    <div>
      <AddUser onAddUser= {addUserHandler}></AddUser>
       <p>{enteredUser.name}</p>
    </div>
  );  ------------> not able to see it here also